# MPI, avoid copying very large objects

Tags: c++, mpi, shared-memory

I have a large instance of a C++ class, containing lots of pointers and references to lots of data structures, in my serial code. It is now needed to implement a linear solver which works in parallel using MPI. Note that the code will run on a shared-memory architecture not a cluster. I am afraid I should rewrite the whole class structure of my program.

However, I am wondering if there is a safe way to access such a large object, created by a master process, within all other processes.

I've searched a lot, but the only way seems to be sending/receiving data after a serialization, e.g. using boost, which leads to repeated copying of a bunch of data during the run-time.

The current structure of my code is:

```
    int main()
    { 
      my_data struct1;
      read_file(&struct1);

      my_data struct2;
      read_file(&struct2);

      data_container data(&struct1, &struct2);

      float time = 0;

      while(time < end_time)
      {    
        do_some_calc(&data);

       //a linear solver should be added here.
        sparse_matrix MATRIX;
        vector RHS, unknowns;
        create_coeff_matrix(&data, &MATRIX);
        create_RHS_vector(&data, &RHS);
        trilinos_solver(&MATRIX, &RHS, &unknowns);
      //--------------------------------------------

        update(&data, &unknowns);
        time++;
      }
      return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Your description of your problem is a bit vague, can you give use more details? Why do you feel you'd need to rewrite the whole thing? How do you plan to do the parallel implementation?

Comment: Any reason you want to use Mpi for such a case which seems, from what you say, more suited for shared memory parallelism? Have you looked at openmp directives ?

Comment: I need to solve a large system of linear equations (using Trilinos). The most performance can be achieved using MPI even on a shared-memory system. I have tested the OMP enabled built and it was more time-consuming than the serial version.

Comment: Under MPI the various processes all have their own address space, just like separate programs.  One of the implications of this is that pointers on one process are meaningless on any other.  If you want to send a complex object from one process to another, yes, you will have to serialise it somehow.

Comment: Trilinos has a pretty good reputation.  I'm surprised that their OpenMP implementation is slower than a serial version.  That's information I would definitely share with the Trilinos team and dig into further.

Comment: "I'm surprised that their OpenMP implementation is slower than a serial version"; let's say that I am using Epetra+Belos compiled with MSVC11.